# Under iOS, is there a quick way to see what symbols I have for specific UUID's?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, symbols, fat-binaries

Under iOS, unique identifiers, known as UUID's, are assigned at compile time. Over time, a developer may accumulate many builds with different identifiers. Sometimes it may be useful to quickly identify what UUID's have preserved symbol files associated with them. Is there a quick way to identify which UUID's have preserved symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the command-line. Replace YourAppName with your real application's name.

```
mdfind 'com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids = *' | grep YourAppName | grep dSYM | sed 's, ,\\&,g' | xargs dwarfdump --uuid
```